# How can I find font references in a Photoshop PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, cs6

**I need to convert all fonts in a PSD file (CS6) to outlines for printing preparation.**

Unfortunately, fonts aren't just in text objects; there are a lot of Smart Objects and some of them may have text in them.

Is there anyway to find out if there are any font references in the entire file?

One thing I have tried is to save the file as PDF, then open it in Acrobat, choose Properties, and see if there are any embedded fonts.  I don't know if that's enough of a guarantee though.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I thought a PSD file would still render the type correctly sans fonts...you just can't edit them. That said, your PDF method *should* be enough.

Comment: Never had this problem myself. With that said, did the PDF trick show you fonts? Have you tried doing a simple test: Create PSD with (multiple?) smart object with various fonts inside each smart object. Next, use PDF technique and see if all fonts are listed. If that works, you may be able to answer your own question. :)

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to keep this as a PSD to print?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantly rasterize all the layers. This will remove all text/font information from them (including those that are smart objects).
When sending .psd files in the past and dealing with printers this was the route I chose.

PRO TIP: before doing this, save this file: "filename_outlines.psd" because once you save and close, you cannot edit the text without redoing.

**Layer > Rasterize > All Layers**

Answer (score 0):

Open the 'Character' window and click on the font dropdown menu (the one you use to change typeface). At the bottom will be a greyed out list of all missing fonts used in the document.